# Get bank account information via Adsense API

Tags: google-api, adsense-api

Is it possible to get payout bank account information via Adsense API? I was not able to find that info in API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get payment data for your account with the AdSense Management API.

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/payments/list

Comment: Thanks but payments are just scheduled or executed "transactions", not bank details.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So you're looking for bank account number, etc.? No, that information is not retrievable from the AdSense Management API.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for bank account number. Thanks!